# Is there a way to personalize/define the bbox or latlong of lookup_coords from the rtweet package?

Tags: r, rtweet

I want to make a Twitter search, specifying the location. I am using the rtweet package. However, when I print the 'lookup_coords' function for the country of Venezuela or the city of Caracas, there are no results. I have followed all advices from previous posts and nothing have helped. 
I have my own Google Api Key
I am working on R, Windows 7.

Is there any possibility to self define the coordinates and assign it to the 'search_tweets' function? How do I know which is the proper syntax for naming every city or country in the world? Is there a list somewhere?

```
lookup_coords(address = "Venezuela", components = "country:Venezuela", apikey = "XXXXXXX")
```

the result is:

```
$place
[1] "Venezuela"

$box
NULL

$point
NULL

attr(,"class")
[1] "coords" "list"
```

when I check the API, all works fine:

```
identical(Sys.getenv("GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY"),rtweet:::find_google_geocode_key())
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: You can try using another geocoding function. With `tmaptools` package you can do `geocode_OSM("caracas")`. [Here's](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tmaptools/tmaptools.pdf) the package documentation

Comment: When I do that I get the following error: "Error in rt[[i]] : subscript out of bounds"  `> geocode_OSM("caracas")
$`query`
`[1] "caracas"

$coords
       x        y 
-66.9146  10.5061 

$bbox
    xmin     ymin     xmax     ymax 
-67.0746  10.3461 -66.7546  10.6661 `

Comment: `ccs_coord <- geocode_OSM("caracas")`                              
           `search_CCS_basura <- search_tweets("gobierno",  n=no.of.tweets, lang="es, include_rts = FALSE, retryonratelimit = TRUE, token = token, lookup_coords = ccs_coord$coords) `

Comment: I do the previous and I get the error:  "Error in rt[[i]] : subscript out of bounds"

Comment: That's because the output from `geocode_OSM` is different from `lookup_coords`. You can try changing output names. For example: `coord_caracas %<>% purrr::set_names("place", "point", "box")` and then, `names(coord_caracas$point) <- c("lng", "lat")`. Let me know if it works.

Comment: I really tried, but I get still the same error. Also I didn't manage to reorder the components of the list  `ccs_coord <- geocode_OSM("caracas")`
`names(ccs_coord) <- c("place", "point", "box")`
`names(ccs_coord$point) <- c("lat", "lng")` This doesnt work as well: `ccs_coord <- ccs_coord[order(c("`place`", "box", "point"))]`

Comment: That's because `lookup_coords` argument on `search_tweets` uses function with same name, that requires a character instead of a numeric vector of coordinates. One option is trying to get all tweets you want, and filter by country: `rt %>% filter(country %in% "Venezuela")` (this returns me a tibble with 213 rows.